# Xgboost Parameter Tuning Random search

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, gridsearchcv

I am using below xgboost parameter tuning code using random search

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor

parameters = {'objective':['reg:squarederror'],
              'booster':['gbtree','gblinear'],
              'learning_rate': [0.1], 
              'max_depth': [7,10,15,20],
              'min_child_weight': [10,15,20,25],
              'colsample_bytree': [0.8, 0.9, 1],
              'n_estimators': [300,400,500,600],
              "reg_alpha"   : [0.5,0.2,1],
              "reg_lambda"  : [2,3,5],
              "gamma"       : [1,2,3]}

xgb_model = XGBRegressor(random_state=30)

grid_obj_xgb = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb_model,parameters, cv=5,n_iter=15,scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',verbose=5,n_jobs=12)
grid_obj_xgb.fit(df_train, y_train,verbose = 1)

y_pred_train = grid_obj_xgb.predict(df_train)
y_pred_test = grid_obj_xgb.predict(df_test)

err_xgb_train=mean_absolute_error(y_train, y_pred_train, multioutput='raw_values')
```

I have rows 1,200,000, columns 75  in my df_train and it is taking lot of time , Is there anything I am doing wrong because of which it is taking so much time or is there any way I can speed up apart from using all cores
or it will take time considering the size of data I have.

I am able to run for one iteration and able to get result so my code is not wrong, However for one iteration also it is taking lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out Bayesian Optimization using [hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) for hyperparameter tuning instead of RandomSearch.  This allows us to rapidly zone in on the optimal parameter set using a probabilistic approach. Since random search is consuming a lot of time for you, chances are you will not be able to find an optimal solution easily.

Also using hyperopt you can customize your search space smartly [(see here)](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin)

I have tried it personally using the hyperopt library in python and it works really well. Check out [this tutorial](https://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/parameter-tuning-with-hyperopt) for more information. You can also download the associated notebook from my [GitHub](https://github.com/ShaunakSen/Data-Science-and-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Parameter_Tuning_with_Hyperopt.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a 5 CV starting from a quite big dataset formed by 1200000x75 values: it is normal it takes quite a lot of time to run. Here you have a number of different options to speed up computations. As @Shaunak pointed out, you might want to try with hyperopt, which generally converges after a few iterations. Also, depending on the specific problem your are trying to solve and the data you have you might want to try one or more of the following:

- Use CatBoost or LightGBM. They are based on different decision tree implementations and are generally quicker than XGBoost.
- Sample down the dataset to reduce the number of rows
- Do some sort of feature selection or dimensionality reduction (e.g. PCA) to reduce the number of columns
- Consider to build smaller number of trees (reduce the number of estimators)
- Consider to build smaller trees (reducing the maximum depth)
- Consider to use other (and generally simpler) models running faster (e.g. linear regressions). Given the amount of data you have you might still obtain good performances.
- Reduce the number of folds you use in the cross validation, maybe by using a separated validation set with early stopping.